# Multiply two values from api response and sum all the results

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting info from an api, and what i wanna do is to multiply two different values from that response, and then sum the totals. I know how to sum all the values with reduce:

```
        function getHistoricSales(){
         $http.get('api/SomeApi')
         .then(function(data){
            $scope.salesResult = data.data.Response;

                var hResults = $scope.salesResult.reduce((a, b) => a + b.Cost, 0);
                $scope.historic = hResult.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
               });
            }
```

But, if per example, on that response not only get the Cost `(b.Cost)`, but the Quantity too. So, how can i in first place multiply every `Cost`by it's own `Quantity` and then sum the results?

I'm using Javascript and AngularJs.

Hope you can help me. Thanx in advance...

Comment: `(a, b) => a + (b.Cost * b.Quantity)` ?

Comment: Thanx, maybe sounds toó obvious but right nos, i have muy brain so tired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
var hResults = $scope.salesResult
                       .map(sr => sr.Cost * sr.Quantity)
                       .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

So you want to transform each sales result (with `map`) into its own result (i.e. cost * quantity) and then sum those (with `reduce`).

For example:

```js
let data = [
 {Cost: 10, Quantity: 15},
 {Cost: 5, Quantity: 11},
 {Cost: 2, Quantity: 110},
 {Cost: 5, Quantity: 90},
]

let result = data
              .map(sr => sr.Cost * sr.Quantity)
              .reduce((a, b) => a + b);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If each item in `$scope.salesResult` optionally has a `quantity` property, you'll need to make sure you're not multiplying by an `undefined` value. Thus, your `reduce()` should take this condition into account.

```js
var salesResult = [
  // Some items only have the cost
  { cost: 10 },
  { cost: 10 },
  // Some items might also have a quantity
  { cost: 10, quantity: 10 },
  { cost: 10, quantity: 10 },
];

var hResults = salesResult.reduce((total, result) =>
  total + (result.quantity
    ? result.cost * result.quantity
    : result.cost), 0);
    
console.log(hResults); // 220
```